# Can I have different bootstrapped entry points for the same Angular module on different pages?

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-modules

I have a tool built in Angular that is loaded within another CMS so the whole site is not an Angular app and Angular is not handling routing. On one page is a sophisticated tool that allows users to add and update their data, on the other I want to display some overview charts. I would like to use the same code for both so that users aren't having to download the same libraries twice.

I have tried setting up my chart tool as a second bootstrap option using `bootstrap: [DataTracker, PortalRingChartComponent]`. In my "Data Tracker" page I have the component referenced `<data-tracker></data-tracker>` and it works correctly, but on the "Portal" page I have `<portal-ring-chart></portal-ring-chart>` and I see the following error:

```
VM3183:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: selectorNode is not defined
    at eval (eval at selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:2837), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:2837)
```

Followed shortly by:

```
ERROR Error: The selector "data-tracker" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:2840)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.js:519)
```

So it looks like the absence of the `data-tracker` element in the page causes it to fail, although the other bootstrapped component is referenced in the page. Not having the `portal-ring-chart` on the "Data Tracker" page does not appear to have the same effect.

I am wondering whether this is a misunderstanding on my part- is it possible to have two independent entry points in a single Angular module? If so, how do I go about it? If not is the simplest workaround just to add selector component as the root of my app that switches between `data-tracker` and `portal-ring-chart` based on input property switch?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this by taking control of my bootstrapping process manually, something that I take from [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/bisubus/fbef01fdb3b14e7349aead9b00701260)

Effectively I have removed the `bootstrap` element from the `NGModule` replacing it with `entryComponents` and then taken control of the bootstrapping process directly using `DoBootstrap`.

```js
@NgModule({
    // a bunch of stuff
    entryComponents: [DataTracker, PortalRingChartComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
    static bootstrapComponents: Type<{}>[] = [DataTracker, PortalRingChartComponent];

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any,
        private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) { }

    ngDoBootstrap(applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {
        for (const component of AppModule.bootstrapComponents) {
            const { selector } = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

            if (this._document.querySelector(selector)) {
                applicationRef.bootstrap(component);
            }
        }
    }
}
```